# Compass won't compile without "sudo compass watch"

Tags: ruby, terminal, sudo, compass-sass

### The Scenario

I'm switching from Codekit to the command line and have run into a weird issue. Anytime I want compass to watch a directory by entering `compass watch`, I get this strange error:

```
Errno::EACCES on line ["1144"] of /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb: Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.19/stylesheets/.listen_test
```

After some testing, I found out that if I enter `sudo compass watch`, the error does not appear, and compass compiles like a beaut.

The problem must be with my permissions. Sudo gives root level access to the system, and by having to use a sudo command, I can tell that my permissions must be wonky.

The real question is, **what's the fix?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to avoid `sudo` which worked for me after encountering the same issue was to go to the directory

`/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.19/`

and give yourself read/write access on that folder and all enclosed folders. Assuming you're on a Mac since you were using CodeKit, select the folder and hit `cmd+i` then hit `+` near the bottom of the window to add yourself (if not already listed). Enable Read & Write access. Finally, hit the gear icon and select `Apply to enclosed items`